# Ng-Style : Unable to pass data over to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am doing an ionic application which uses angular-js. Using ng-repeat, i populate the results. I would like to display different colours based on different criteria.

I have managed to do just one criteria using the inline ng-style coding as follows:

```
<table ng-style="{color:(test.Status == 'Cleared')?'green' : 'red'}">
```

It works perfectly fine, but if I do wish to set more criteria like time and etc, then inline would not be a viable option.

Thus I tried to changed it to controller via this.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="test in tests" class ="item-text-wrap" style="height:40%">

    <a href="#/tab/test/test-detail/{{test.ID}}">
    <div style="width:80%; float:left;">

    <table>
    <span ng-style="calculateStyle(test)">
    <tr>
        <td> <strong>Remark: </strong></td>
        <td style="padding:3px">{{test.Remark}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Status:</strong></td>
        <td style="padding:3px">{{test.Status}}</td>
    </tr>
        </span>
    </table>

</div>
</a>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

In my controller class,

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http, $cordovaSQLite, dataFactory, StoreService) {
....
  $scope.calculateStyle = function(test) {
      var style={}
      if (test.Status  == 'Cleared') {
      style.color='green';
      console.log('Viola');
    }
    else{
      console.log('GG');
    }
      return style;
  }
```

Note:Tests is an JSON data retrieved from webservice which has many objects. Thus , the need for ng-repeat and I'm trying to get every test.Status value to do colour coding.

For some reasons I do not know why, it throws me an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token test

at the

```
$scope.calculateStyle = function(test)
```

**I can pass integer or string over via calculateStyle('Test') or calculateStyle(123) , it works perfectly fine. Just that passing 'case' has problems.**

I tried to replace it with '$scope' but still no avail. What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: can you console log the `test` inside the `calculateStyle`?

Comment: you need to return an object like `{ 'color' : 'green'}` you may want to double check that is what you are getting back. Also just try and log test make sure you are passing it.

Comment: Hi sorry, I debugged too much and forgotten that the error undefined was for the scope. This original code returns me uncaught syntaxError.

Comment: can you provide a plunkr ?

Comment: it means you have something typed incorrectly, try re-typing it by hand. Sometimes copy/pasting can do this, or you just missed something small.

Comment: @ajmajmajma, I typed everything by hand. I have been stuck at this for days.

Comment: show the whole file plz

Comment: drop the whole section of code in a plunkr or something

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi, Im unable as i retrieve those data over from webservice itself. I have added my respective page controller declarations at the question.

Comment: what's in the `tests` ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi, tests is an JSON data retrieved from webservice which has many objects. Thus , the need for ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
<table ng-init="sloppy = case" ng-style="calculateStyle(sloppy)">
```

does the trick.

Comment: Hi, i did close but i did not put it in. my bad. I edit now.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi if there is an uncaught syntaxerror, then the whole view and web application is white, unable to see anything.

Comment: Before you look further, would you try changing to `ng-href`? That is important

Comment: Ohhhhh I think the problem is that you can't pass test into the function like that, give me a sec

Comment: If i put integer or string in the calculateStyle, everything works fine. Just passing the 'case' has problems.

Comment: that makes sense, try something like `ng-init="sloppy = test"` in the `<table>` tag, then pass `testt` in instead.  Its ugly so if it works don't leave it like that

Comment: sorry i meant `sloppy` not `testt`

Comment: if that doesn't work try `ng-init="temp = angular.copy(test)"`